# How to draw a line from a NODE to the X-AXIS?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can't seem to make my nodes behave correctly. A simple secant line on a bezier curve. Identify the delta-X and delta-Y of that secant. The problem lies when I try to extend the delta-X segment downwards to the x-axis. See code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}       
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (12,0) node[anchor=north west] (X) {x};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[anchor=south east] (Y) {f(x)};
\draw (1,1) .. controls (7,1) and (8,2) .. (9,5)
    node[inner sep=0cm,pos=.3](P){}
    node[inner sep=0cm,pos=.8](Q){};
\draw[blue,thick] (P) -- (Q);
\draw[gray]  (P)  --  node[below] {$\Delta{X}$} (P -| Q); 
\draw[gray]  (P -| Q)  --  node[right] {$\Delta{Y}$} (Q);
\draw[fill] (P) circle [radius=0.075] node[above left] (P) {P};
\draw[fill] (Q) circle [radius=0.075] node[right] (Q) {Q};
\node [above] at (9,5) {y = f(x)};
\draw[->,red] (P) -- (P |- X);
\draw[red] (P -| Q) -- (Q |- X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fig. 1]

Solved!

[image: Fig. 2]

Now I just need to add a few labels... hopefully it will be uneventful!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a minimal working example (MWE), including `documentclass`, `usepackage`, `begin{document}`, so we can easily reproduce the problem. Also, if possible, include an image or link to show what you want (presumably here to have red arrows from your nodes to the x-axis?).

Comment: Use `{(0,0)}` instead of `X` in the last two lines. You can see why this is happening by adding `draw` option to the node `X`

Comment: @percusse Thanks! This solves the overshooting problem but the misalignment still remains. Paul Gessler solved that one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is correct, except the coordinate `(X)` is located at the center anchor of the node, so the arrows extend too far.

Simply place a coordinate `(X)` instead of naming the label node `(X)`:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (12,0) coordinate (X) node[anchor=north west] {x};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,6) node[anchor=south east] (Y) {f(x)};
\draw (1,1) .. controls (7,1) and (8,2) .. (9,5)
    node[inner sep=0cm,pos=.3](P){}
    node[inner sep=0cm,pos=.8](Q){};
\draw[blue,thick] (P) -- (Q);
\draw[gray]  (P)  --  node[below] {$\Delta{X}$} (P -| Q); 
\draw[gray]  (P -| Q)  --  node[right] {$\Delta{Y}$} (Q);
\draw[fill] (P) circle [radius=0.075] node[above left] (P) {P};
\draw[fill] (Q) circle [radius=0.075] node[right] (Q) {Q};
\node [above] at (9,5) {y = f(x)};
\draw[->,red] (P) -- (P |- X);
\draw[red] (P -| Q) -- (Q |- X);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use a similar approach with the other node names (`P`, `Q`, etc.) if those alignments are not what you intended either.

Comment: Indeed these alignments are *not* what I intended... they have to align with the P and Q points. I tried inserting `coordinate (P)` prior to the `node` command for both P and Q to no avail.

Comment: @ebann you also have to *remove* the node name (change `node[above left] (P) {P}` to `node[above left] {P}`) otherwise your new coordinate is immediately overwritten.

Comment: Gotcha! I just realized `\draw[fill] (P) circle [radius=0.075] node[above left] (P) {P};` redefined my `(P)` coordinate defined in the bezier function. Removing `(P)` as you suggested solved my problems! Thanks!

Comment: Need one more help... when I try to add labels to these extensions, i.e. `X` below the `(P)` and `X+dX` below the `(Q)`, I can't get the label to be added *below* the x-axis, e.g. `\draw[dashed,red] (P) -- node[below right] {X} (P |- X);` adds the label *above* the x-axis...

Comment: I figured it out... just moved the *label* to the right side of the *point*, i.e. `\draw[dashed,red] (P) -- (P |- X) node[below] {X};` I have to go back to the manual and understand the nitty gritty of TikZ!

Comment: @ebann glad you figured it out. Please also use math mode for any maths, that way everything looks consistent and math spacing is managed for you (compare `y = f(x)` vs. `$y = f(x)$` and other places too).